# Permanently change permissions of /var/run/postgresql

Tags: permissions, linux-mint, chmod, chown, postgresql

On Linux Mint 17.0 Cinnamon Edition, I want to use `/var/run/postgresql` as the `unix_socket_directories` option for all of my postgres databases.

Whenever I run the command `pg_ctl -D postgres-data -o '-F -p 33311' start` to start my local database, I get the error `FATAL:  could not create lock file "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.33311.lock": Permission denied`.

As many answers across AskUbuntu, StackOverflow and various forums suggest, I have to run `sudo chmod 777 /var/run/postgresql` or `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/run/postgresql` to change the permissions of the directory so that I can write to it. Then I am able to start my database. However, every time I reboot, the permissions go away; the directory is no longer world-writable and the user `postgres-xc` reclaims user and group ownership over the directory.

Neither `sudo adduser $USER postgres` or `sudo adduser $USER postgres-xc` alleviates the permissions issue.

I tried doing a clean install as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28947498/ubuntu-psql-could-not-connect-to-server), but I still have the issue on reboot.

I've tried changing the value of `unix_socket_directories` to `/tmp` in `./postgres-data/postgresql.conf` (the local database config file), and this allows me to start that particular database without having to update permissions on every reboot. However, I also have a script which uses `pg_ctl -D $DIR initdb && pg_ctl -D $DIR start` to setup and start databases on the fly. As such, a default `postgresql.conf` config file is used for these databases, so `unix_socket_directories` is the unwritable `/var/run/postgresql` and I get permission denied errors when running that script. Manually/programmatically editing these configs on-the-fly to use `unix_socket_directories = '/tmp'` is... undesirable.

I know that I could use the `-o` flag with `pg_ctl` to override the `unix_socket_directories` option to `/tmp`, but this script is shared by other developers who do not use Ubuntu, so I would not necessarily want to restrict everyone to using the `/tmp` directory, especially if their configurations differed slightly. I would prefer everyone use the default location for their installation. Personally, I would also prefer to keep the default directory for general compatibility with other Ubuntu packages; e.g., pgadmin looks at `/var/run/postgresql` for a lock file by default.

I have also tried editing `/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_ctl.conf` in an attempt to automatically pass set these options whenever I use `pg_ctl`:

```
# Automatic pg_ctl configuration
# This configuration file contains cluster specific options to be passed to
# pg_ctl(1).

pg_ctl_options = '-o "-c unix_socket_directories=/tmp -c unix_socket_group=jackson -c unix_socket_permissions=0777"'
```

But that did not have any effect.

Please advise on how I can use `/var/run/postgresql` as my `unix_socket_directories` option for all of my postgres databases without having to run `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/run/postgresql` every time I restart my system. Thanks.

Comment: What kind of file system is sitting in? When you reboot/restart the system, does this directory exist?  Just wondering if this is sitting in a tmpfs file system or similar.

Comment: Whatever the default file system is for a user installation of Linux Mint 17.0; ext4 I think.

Comment: After a reboot, does the directory exist?

Comment: Yes, the directory exists.

Comment: X-post from http://askubuntu.com/q/631112/75715

Comment: I flagged the other post for takedown, Craig.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Permissions for /var/run/postgresql are taken from /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/postgresql.conf

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I don’t use Linux Mint any more but I’m going to take it on faith that this is right.

Comment: At what point do these permissions get set from the file? I ran chmod on the file and it worked...restarted the server and nothing changed. Is it created on boot or under some other circumstance?

Answer (score 1):

Run the following to reclaim the directory (immediately and on subsequent boots):

```
service='reclaim-postgresql'
service_file="/etc/init.d/${service}"

echo "#!/bin/sh
set -e

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          ${service}
# Required-Start:    \$postgres-xc
# Required-Stop:     \$postgres-xc
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Reclaim /var/run/postgresql
### END INIT INFO

chown -R ${USER}:${USER} /var/run/postgresql" \
    | sudo tee "${service_file}"
sudo chmod +x "${service_file}"
sudo update-rc.d "${service}" defaults
sudo service "${service}" start
```

Note that when running `sudo apt-get upgrade` to update postgres, you may need to temporarily `sudo chown -R postgres:postgres /var/run/postgresql` in order for the upgrade to succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your init system, add the chown/chmod command in the relevant init script for PostgreSQL such as `/etc/init.d/postgresql`.

Answer (score 0):

use `pg_ctl -D ... -o "... -k /tmp" start`  to create the socket in `/tmp`